# How to Store ArrayList Of Custom Objects (Geofence)

Tags: java, android, gson, android-geofence

I'm trying to store **List of Geofences** in **sharedPreferences** using **Gson**.
This is what I've done so far

```
           ArrayListOfGeofence listOfGeofence = new ArrayListOfGeofence();

            listOfGeofence.setmGeofencesList(mGeofenceList);

            editor = goefenceIdsPreferences.edit();

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            String json = gson.toJson(listOfGeofence.mGeofencesList);

            Log.i(TAG, "Json Geofence Objects: " + json);

            editor.putString(fenceName, json).commit();
```

Things are not expected as it should be.This is what my log shows:

```
Json Geofence Objects: [{"Jo":"1","NU":3,"Oz":-1,"NX":12.93217,"NY":77.63186,"NZ":300.0,"Oa":0,"Ob":-1,"NW":1,"xH":1}]
```

My Actual Geofence ArrayList is:

```
ArrayListOfGeofence: [Geofence[CIRCLE id:1 transitions:3 12.932490, 77.630830 300m, resp=0s, dwell=-1ms, @-1], Geofence[CIRCLE id:2 transitions:3 12.934540, 77.628650 300m, resp=0s, dwell=-1ms, @-1]]
```

And this is what I've written for **ArrayListOfGeofence** class

```
public class ArrayListOfGeofence implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

List<Geofence> mGeofencesList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();


public List<Geofence> getmGeofencesList()
{
    return mGeofencesList;
}

public void setmGeofencesList(List<Geofence> mGeofencesList) 
{
    this.mGeofencesList = mGeofencesList;
}

}
```

But I'm unable to retrieve back my Geofence Objects.and so it gives me an error :

```
GSON Generic: failed to deserialized json object
```

Comment: write Method to deserialize generic collection:

Comment: that's a different story i'm not even able to store it serialize it properly.

Comment: so check the place you are parsing the json , what you are getting in `Log.i(TAG, "Json Geofence Objects: " + json);`

Comment: I've updated my question,you can see my logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use shared preference for this.  Its not made for it, and the purpose of shared preference isn't to store everything.  You already have it as JSON, just save the json as a file

Comment: I know its a bad practise to store everything in sharedpreferences, but you can see even json isn't correct as expected.

Comment: But if you already have the data as json (even broken json) and can parse it as such, why not just use that format?  All the code is written except the write to the file.

Comment: yeah you are right.. for the time being I can do that.Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Edit the line:
 String json = gson.toJson(listOfGeofence.mGeofencesList);
By:
  String json = gson.toJson(listOfGeofence.getmGeofencesList());